# get value fot title from XML document

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, sharepoint-2010, xml-parsing

hey all ! i have a jquery that hits a Query on the sharepoint server & fetches the result in the form of XML document that look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <QueryResponse xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search">
      <QueryResult>
        <ResponsePacket xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response">
          <Response>
            <Range>
              <StartAt>1</StartAt>
              <Count>1</Count>
              <TotalAvailable>1</TotalAvailable>
              <Results>
                <Document xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document">
                  <Action>
                    <LinkUrl>http://ishaan1519:1234/Lists/Discussions/where are 401k benefit investment prospectus</LinkUrl>
                  </Action>
                  <Properties xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document">
                    <Property>
                      <Name>TITLE</Name>
                      <Type>String</Type>
                      <Value>where are 401k benefit investment prospectus</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                      <Name>PATH</Name>
                      <Type>String</Type>
                      <Value>http://ishaan1519:1234/Lists/Discussions/where are 401k benefit investment prospectus</Value>
                    </Property>
                  </Properties>
                </Document>
              </Results>
            </Range>
            <Status>SUCCESS</Status>
          </Response>
        </ResponsePacket>
      </QueryResult>
    </QueryResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i need to populate the text field (#output ) with title & link path 
using this function

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("QueryResult").each(function () {
    var x = $("<xml>" + $(this).text() + "</xml>");

    x.find("Document").each(function () {
        url = $("Action>LinkUrl", $(this)).text();

        title = $("Title", $(this)).text();

        $("#output").append("title: " + title + " - LinkUrl: " + url);
    });
```

i can get the LinkUrl but the title is `null` 
please help me out to populate  the textfield with title . from

```
<Property>
    <Name>TITLE</Name>
    <Type>String</Type>
    <Value>where are 401k benefit investment prospectus</Value>
</Property>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no element Title. TITLE is within the element <Name>

`title = $("Property>Name", $(this)).text();`

Comment: hey sir ! i want to get value for title ie : 'where are 401k benefit investment prospectus' out of ~ <Property> <Name>TITLE</Name> <Type>String</Type> <Value>where are 401k benefit investment prospectus</Value> </Property>~ and title = $("Property>Name", $(this)).text();  returns me TITLE

Comment: title = $("Property>Value", $(this)).text();

Answer (score 1):

SP2010 has a script object model built to make accessing the webservices a lot easier:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://ishaan1519:1234/");
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('/Discussions');   
var q = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Path'/></ViewFields></View>";    
camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
var listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(Title,Path)'); 
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(sender, args) {
    var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext())  {
        var title = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Title");
        var path = listEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Path");
        ///do your stuff
    }
}, function(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
});
```

Comment: hey sir .. there are some conflicts from client that we don't use CAML qyery so we are using <QueryText language='en-US' type='MSSQLFT > & we are hitting server's sql DB. So Please help me out in this context Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a contains selector, but I don't think it has an exact-match selector. Using contains you could do something like

```
    x.find("Document").each(function () {
        url = $("Action>LinkUrl", $(this)).text();

        // find the Name element that contains TITLE
        var $nameTitle = $(this).find("Name:contains('TITLE')");
        // find the containing Property element
        var $property = $nameTitle.closest('Property');
        // find the Value in that Property
        var $value = $property.find('Value');
        // and read text
        var title = $value.text();
```

(obviously you can smash all of those together - expanded for comments). To get just the 'TITLE' element (and not say 'SUBTITLE') I think you'd have to loop, e.g.

```
        var title = null;
        $(this).find('Name').each(function() {
          var $name = $(this);
          if ($name.text() == 'TITLE') {
            title = $name.closest('Property').find('Value').text();
            return false;
          }
        });
```